Get oAuth2 Access token into iOS to end Notification
I need to migrate from Legacy FCM API to new Http V1. I did it successfully in android, where I got ServiceAccont from firebase, then using Google Auth Api, I can get Authorization token, that is sent to my server (php) to send notification. I am stuck  at getting access token from iOS device. I assume i shall use same serviceAccount json file.
Any thoughts ? .. Thanks..

Yes, your server communicates with FCM, so the way it authenticates to FCM is the same regardless of whether it is sending a notification to an Android or an iOS device. You need to get the device token from the iOS device into your database so that you can send that to FCM with the notification payload

yes, but in android , i am getting oAuth2 access token at android device, this is to save load into server. to HTTP message from android phone to my server includes the Auth token. I could do it in android, but how to create Auth token at iOS. . I use in android implementation('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.19.0') {

and my code :  and below code :  try {
InputStream stream = mcontext.getAssets().open("serviceaccount.json");
GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream).createScoped(firebaseMessagingScope);
googleCredentials.refresh();
final String token = googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
// Handle the token here
// token received
} catch (Exception e) {
// error
}

the generated Auth token is created at android device, i pass to my server ,php, to send FCM message

Only your php server should need the Google credentials. It isn't safe for your Google credentials file to be in your android app. You get the APNS token in your iOS app and send that to your server. Your server can use the Google credentials to authenticate to the FcM endpoint and use the token to send the notification to the iOS device.

you mean that my server shall generate the FCM Access token ? If yes, this is not planned , as this will make heave load into my server, what I need to to get access token at device level (ios/android)  >> pass to my server with msg body/title >> php server will send notification . I know the security concern , but i service key data is streamed from server to the android/iOS device, ie , not hardcoded

No. Your android device generates the push FCM token and your iOS devices will provide apns tokens.  These need to be sent to your server to be stored in your database, but you are talking about oauth and Google access credentials and Google identity files. Your server needs to authenticate to the FCM service using the Google identity file. Neither your android app nor your iOS app authenticate to the FCM service.

"Your server needs to authenticate to the FCM service using the Google identity file." >> I think new Google FCM HTTP V1 needs Authorizaiton token in order to send push notification. This Authorization token to be created by ServiceAccount file and oAuth2. When run below php code, it sends notification to both android and iOS. Authorization token is needed by php to send to Google FCM server: $headers = [  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,  'Content-Type: application/json',  ];

Sorry for misClarification . I need the Authorization key that will be needed to send push notificaiton to Google FCM server.  this is sent into POST request Header as below : Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA .  NB: I can get android FCM device token and iPhone APN token which is passed into message part. What  I need is the Authorization key
$headers = [  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $AuthorizKey,  'Content-Type: application/json',  ];
$message = [ 'token' => $device_token, 'notification' => [  'title' => $title, 'body' => $body,  ], ];

Yes.  Only your server needs the credential to create that token. It can obtain it using the credentials json file. It should be stored securely on your server.

i need the Authorization access token to be created into iOS , not created at server, to save server workload. I do it already in android, where android device creates the Access token,  and passes it to server, then server can create push notification Post request , to certain topic.

It is not secure to give your mobile apps permission to create access tokens for Google services. To do so you need to have your Google identity file embedded in the iOS app, where it can be extracted. On,y your server should have access to this file. Your mobile app should provide the FCM/apns tokens to your server. Your server uses a Google identity to create an auth token so that it can send notifications to the mobile devices via the FCM api.

Streaming the key file from your server to the app doesn't make it any more secure, because anyone can stream it from your server.  Creating an access token in your serve should not be much of a load. You only need to do it very 60. Inures or so; cache the token and only refresh it when it expires.

your proposal to create access token is good if i can cache it and refresh it when it expires. but how to cache it in php. this will be quite difficult since php handles each API call as new instance , so i cannot cache the generated access token. What I have to is to get access token each API call , which will be excessive load into server resouces

Does your service have the ability to write a file to a temporary directory?  If so, there is a cache; persist the token to a file. You could also consider runnjng your service in Google cloud. Google cloud functions and cloud run instances are implicitly authenticated to Google services

can you add you post for "Creating an access token in your serve should not be much of a load." as an answer . I will approve it as answer.  I have used Google API client to create the access token into server.  your proposal supported me. Thanks..
